TGI with Mixtral-8x7B CUDA no kernel image available error
I have a system with the following configuration:
Nvidia Quadro RTX 8000 GPU with 48GB VRAM
Nvidia SMI driver version 550.90.07 with CUDA version 12.4
nvidia-container-toolkit version 1.15.0
I'm trying to use the above with huggingface TGI in a container with docker as the runtime.  I'm currently using TGI image version 2.0.4 (ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:2.0.4).
I started using the mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1 and that has been working fine, no problems.  I wanted to try using Mixtral-8x7B and I have run into a wall.  The main Mixtral-8x7B model is too large for my single 48GB GPU so I wanted to try to use one of the quantized variants.
Specifically I have tried both TheBloke/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1-AWQ and TheBloke/mixtral-8x7b-v0.1-AWQ.
I start the TGI container with the following parameters: --model-id TheBloke/Mixtral-8x7B-v0.1-AWQ --quantize awq --max-input-length 3696 --max-total-tokens 4096 --max-batch-prefill-tokens 4096
I also set the environment variable HF_HUB_ENABLE_HF_TRANSFER=false.
With either of the Mixtral variants it appears to start normally and then at the end I get the following error:
Method Warmup encountered an error.
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
I get the same outcome with either Mixtral variant AWQ variant.  To reiterate, nothing above is any different when using Mistral7b-Instruct-v0.1 successfully.  Most related posts I can find regarding this error talk about the need to recompile torch to work with your specific GPU or use a different version of CUDA / driver, etc. I've explored those possibilities but none of that seems to jive with the fact that the same configuration works fine with a different model and everything else the same.  The torch version and other libraries are tied to what is in the TGI image which again works fine with Mistral and this GPU.  That said, my experience here is limited.  I am unable to find any posts that seem relevant to my specific problem.  If anybody has any ideas or can at least help me understand the error better in this context it would be very much appreciated.  I have seen various mentions that seem to imply others have gotten Mixtral-8x7B working with TGI so I'm hopeful it is possible.
Expecting to be able to swap out a supported model with the correct parameters and have it work.  I have tried different versions of the Nvidia driver and CUDA as well as different versions of the TGI image and a few different 4 bit quantized versions of Mixtral-8x7B and all result in the same error.  In each case all of these configurations worked fine with the same GPU and the Mistral-7B model.
